# How to write custom layout in ExtJs 4 or 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I want to write my own layout.. (like `vbox`, `border` and so one)... What i want to do is to create layout that will place it's content in the middle (verticall - middle, horisontal - middle)..

**Is there some one who could show me how this control will look like in extJs or can provide some links that may be usefull?**

---

I have this example from

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

```
Ext.ux.layout.CenterLayout = Ext.extend(Ext.layout.FitLayout, {
// private
setItemSize : function(item, size){
    this.container.addClass('ux-layout-center');
    item.addClass('ux-layout-center-item');
    if(item && size.height > 0){
        if(item.width){
            size.width = item.width;
        }
        item.setSize(size);
    }
}
});

Ext.Container.LAYOUTS['ux.center'] = Ext.ux.layout.CenterLayout;
```

But it gives me more questions than answers.. What is `setItemSize` How it works? When? Why? ect. What is `item.setSize` called for? How it works? When? Why? ect.

Comment: why do yo need to write a custom layout? what don't you did with ExtJS's layouts or what is the specific case for you. I am asking this because, I have done many ExtJS based web applications, and when you are using ExtJS, you have a enormous power, you can do almost everything easily without worrying about new layouts or components.

Comment: I just want to create layout that will place items in the vertical and horisontall center, in my applicaton i will use this layout VERY offten so i really need it... am i only one who want to use this layout? o_O

Comment: "place items in the vertical and horisontall center" does not mean anything - at least for me - if you detail the point more clearly - a basic draw might be the best way -, i will try to help you.

Comment: heres an example, open this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html then go to Custom Layouts - Center... ok so i want someting like this, but layout have to align horisontal and vertical center... not only horisontal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the examples of ExtJS 3, there is an `Ext.ux.Layout.CenterLayout` under custom layouts there already, maybe a good point to start?

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

---

Edit: Try this layout user extension, it centers an item in the horizontal and vertical center of it's container

```
Ext.ns('Ext.ux.layout');

Ext.ux.layout.CenterLayout = Ext.extend(Ext.layout.ContainerLayout, {
    monitorResize:true,
    type: 'ux.center',
    getLayoutTargetSize : function() {
        var target = this.container.getLayoutTarget();
        if (!target) {
            return {};
        }
        return target.getStyleSize();
    },
    onLayout : function(ct, target){
        Ext.ux.layout.CenterLayout.superclass.onLayout.call(this, ct, target);
        if(!ct.collapsed){
            this.setItemSize(this.activeItem || ct.items.itemAt(0), this.getLayoutTargetSize());
        }
    },
    setItemSize : function(item, size){
        var left = (size.width - item.getWidth()) / 2;
        var top  = (size.height - item.getHeight()) / 2;

        var pos = Ext.apply(item.getEl().getPositioning(), {
            position : 'absolute',
            left     : left,
            top      : top
        });
        item.getEl().setPositioning(pos);
    }
});
Ext.Container.LAYOUTS['ux.center'] = Ext.ux.layout.CenterLayout;
```

Comment: Ye i saw that example.. but i'm too stupid :) so i actually didn't get anything..

Comment: You also looked at the sourcecode of the layout extension? If you want to write your own layout manager that's the best you can get i'm afraid, http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/ux/CenterLayout.js

Comment: did you wrote 'custom' layout by your self?

Comment: What do you mean? If i've ever written an Ext Layoutmanager myself?

Comment: I mean... do you ever written a 'custom' Layout manager by yourself?

Comment: Check my anwser, i've updated it with a user extension layout that should fit your needs. It centers both horizontally and vertically

Comment: I tried this in ExtJs 3.2.1 and it's not working.. http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/TrainApp.zip for some rison `top` and `left` is not assigned.. http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/noname.png (image is clickable)

Comment: i just add this line `item.getEl().setLocation(left, top); ` after this `item.getEl().setPositioning(pos);` so now everithing is fine..

Answer (score 2):

[Ext.layout.ContainerLayout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/ContainerLayout.html#cls-Ext.layout.ContainerLayout) (the base class for layouts) has a `doLayout` method that triggers your container rendering.

In the case of [FitLayout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/FitLayout.html#cls-Ext.layout.FitLayout), its overriden and it calls a custom `setItemSize` function who calls the native [setSize](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.style-more.html#method-Ext.Element-setSize) for the first container item (or the  selected item if any), to fit the container size (maximize i guess).

Check also these custom layouts : http://layoutscroll.demo.revolunet.com/

Comment: And how last link connected with 'custom' layot? o_O

Comment: it is a custom layout example, see the code here : http://demo.revolunet.com/gary/demo/Ext.ux.layout.Scroll/src/Ext.ux.layout.Scroll.js

Answer (score 2):

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        items: [
            {
                html: 'Hello World'
            }
        ]
    });
```